# Select random row in SQL where Status = 0 using php

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder... is this possible to select a random row in my DB where only the record that contains `field->Status = 0` ? because i only need a row that contains 0 in the field `name=Status`. if the status `contains = 1` , then the row will not belong in the randomization.

my code in the query is

```
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `$haha` ORDER BY RAND() limit 1");<br>
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `$haha` ORDER BY RAND() limit 1 Where Status=0");
```

But it does not work.. i appreciate your replies.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$haha."` Where Status=0 ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,1");
```

Your where clause should be before then the order by clause.

And want to know what is the value of `$haha`.

Comment: it is the table name.. i declare a session inside it.. Thankyou BTW.. :)

Comment: @AllenTheGreat I will suggest to you to echo or make a check that this  variable has some value or not.

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong syntax. The good one:

```
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `$haha` Where Status=0 ORDER BY RAND() limit 1");
```